# how to inject viewModel into a fragment - dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Hi I am using dagger 2 for dependency injection and when I try to inject MainActivityViewModel in my fragment I get the error `lateinit property viewModelx has not been initialized`

these are the related dependency files and Fragment

RetroModule

```
@Module
class RetroModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getApiService(): ApiServiceInterface =
        getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiServiceInterface::class.java)

    companion object {
        private val baseURL = "https://android-interview.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
    }
}
```

RetroComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [RetroModule::class])
interface RetroComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel)
}
```

Fragment

```
class CreditScoreFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var viewModelx: MainActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCreditScoreBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        initViewModel()
        initView()
        return view
    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModelx.getCreditReportObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<CreditReport> {
            showScoreUI(true)
            binding.score.text = it.creditReportInfo.score.toString()
            binding.maxScoreValue.text = "out of ${it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue}"
            initDonutView(
                it.creditReportInfo.score.toFloat(),
                it.creditReportInfo.maxScoreValue.toFloat()
            )
        })
        viewModelx.getServerErrorLiveDataObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Boolean> {
            if(it) {
                showScoreUI(false)
                showToastMessage()
            }
        })
        viewModelx.getCreditReport()
    }

 companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            CreditScoreFragment().apply {}
    }

}
```

Error update

```
xxx/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/clearscore/di/ViewModelModule.java:18: error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory bindMainActivityViewModel_Factory(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                 ^xxx/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/clearscore/di/RetroComponent.java:18: error: @Component.Factory abstract methods must return the @Component type or a supertype of the @Component. Inherited method: create(T)
    public static abstract class Factory implements dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<com.example.clearscore.MyApplication> {
                           ^xxxapp/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/clearscore/di/RetroComponent.java:6: error: com.example.clearscore.di.ViewModelModule has errors
@dagger.Component(modules = {com.example.clearscore.di.RetroModule.class, com.example.clearscore.di.ViewModelModule.class})
```

ViewModelModule

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class )
    // Bind your View Model here
    abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    // Bind viewModelFactory if you have custom ViewModelFactory
    abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel_Factory(factory: MainActivityViewModel_Factory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

MainActivityViewModel_Factory

```
@DaggerGenerated
@SuppressWarnings({
    "unchecked",
    "rawtypes"
})
public final class MainActivityViewModel_Factory implements Factory<MainActivityViewModel> {
  private final Provider<DataRepository> dataRepositoryProvider;

  public MainActivityViewModel_Factory(Provider<DataRepository> dataRepositoryProvider) {
    this.dataRepositoryProvider = dataRepositoryProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public MainActivityViewModel get() {
    return newInstance(dataRepositoryProvider.get());
  }

  public static MainActivityViewModel_Factory create(
      Provider<DataRepository> dataRepositoryProvider) {
    return new MainActivityViewModel_Factory(dataRepositoryProvider);
  }

  public static MainActivityViewModel newInstance(DataRepository dataRepository) {
    return new MainActivityViewModel(dataRepository);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the provider in your viewmodel module:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class)
abstract fun provideMainActivityViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel
```

Your Fragment must be declared in your module too:

```
@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun provideCreditScoreFragment(): CreditScoreFragment
```

And in your fragment, when you declare the viewmodel, is necessary to init it, for example with a lazy initialization, as you wish:

```
 private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, yourViewModelFactory).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
 }
```

And finally you can inject your viewmodel factory in the fragment (remember to declare the factory in the module)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing onething. Add AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this) in onAttach or onCreate based on when u start using your dependency this will help dagger to inject.